# How to select from multiple rows where and concatenate column values?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `article` (
  `article_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `language_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `article_title` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `article_body` varchar(8192) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `meta_description` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `meta_keyword` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `article_main_image` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `promote` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `deleted` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
  `published` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'1',
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`article_id`,`language_id`),
  KEY `article_title` (`article_title`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

lagnuage_id :

English = 1

Arabic = 2

Russian = 3

I would like to `select * where language_id = 1 limit by 10`, but join the language columns into one if they have the same `article_id`. eg:

```
(1, 1, 0, 'qwq', 'da sdsad as da ds', 'asd sa d', 'as dsadasd as d sa', '', b'0', '2013-06-20 11:01:32', '2013-06-20 08:01:32', b'0', b'1', 0),
(1, 2, 0, '????????', '?? ??? ??? ??? ???', '?? ??? ??? ? ???? ', '??? ??? ?? ???? ?? ???? ', '', b'0', '2013-06-20 11:01:32', '2013-06-20 08:01:32', b'0', b'1', 0),
(1, 3, 0, 'rrrrrrrrrrr', 'rrrr', 'rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr', 'rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr', '', b'0', '2013-06-20 11:01:32', '2013-06-20 08:01:32', b'0', b'1', 0),
```

I want to select rows like this:

```
(1, 1-2-3, 0, 'qwq', 'da sdsad as da ds', 'asd sa d', 'as dsadasd as d sa', '', b'0', '2013-06-20 11:01:32', '2013-06-20 08:01:32', b'0', b'1', 0),
```

Notice how the language ids are joined; I want to be able to know what languages are available for this article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `GROUP BY` and `GROUP_CONCAT` I was able to fix my issue:

```
SELECT  `article_id` , GROUP_CONCAT(  `language_id` ) , ..,..,..,..
FROM  `article` 
GROUP BY  `article_id` 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```